# Docusign envelope creation without signer name

Tags: docusignapi

Is it possible to create a Docusign envelope without giving a name for the signer?

Here is the sample envelope definition from the REST docs

```
{
   "status":"sent",
   "emailSubject":"Example of one recipient, type signer",
   "documents":[
      {
        "documentId":"1",
        "name":"contract.pdf",
        "documentBase64":"base64 document bytes..."
      }
   ],
   "recipients":{
   "signers":[
       {
            "name":"Lisa Simpson",
            "email":"lisa@email.com",
            "recipientId":"1",
            "routingOrder":"1",
            "tabs":{
               "signHereTabs":[
               {
                  "xPosition":"150",
                  "yPosition":"200",
                  "documentId":"1",
                  "pageNumber":"1"
               }]
             }
       }]
    }
}
```

`

Instead of "Lisa Simpson" I want to have a blank string `""` to withhold the persons name. Is this allowed? When I try I get back this error `INVALID_USERNAME_FOR_RECIPIENT` but am wondering if there is a workaround.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Signers need to have names defined.

An exception to this is if you are using a 'specify recipients' role prior to the signer. In this case, you can have a blank placeholder signer, but the Specify user will be required to enter both a name and email for the signer.

What is your use case for a signer without a name?

Comment: Thanks for the info Drew. The use case is that we have a specific client not wanting their name appearing on the document. We are working with them to let them know this is not feasible. Thanks!

Comment: Interesting. In that case you'd need to enter 'xxxxxx' or something similar to obscure it.